Is the Protestant work ethic still valid at large(not in details)
Correct me if I am wrong but the idea of the Protestant work ethic is that once you knock down the reassurance of salvation through the Church and instead rely on the bible and faith alone then the resulting soteriological and eschatological anxiety drove protestants of early reformation into some other source of confirmation for their own personal salvation.
I heard that early attempts at Christian communes with socialist-like organization failed and thus the early Reformists established prosperity, constant work and toil, and success(aka money) as a marker of the aforementioned marker of salvation.
Even though no one in modern days would call themselves a Calvinist many modern denominations have picked up this core ideas and thus many protestants see wealthy people as likely to be chosen by God(or tempted by the devil for a tiny minority of non believing rich people) and poor people as deserving of poverty and their poverty a direct result of their "laziness", only a tiny minority of true Christian paupers are being put to the test by God.
So work correlates with success if you believe it! Thus capitalism is propelled by believer desperate to save themselves through dedication to early capitalists. Hence the success of many protestant countries(I think (this is my personal belief) this last point is probably wrong as colonization and the fact that the protestant countries where lucky enough to have the Industrial Revolution and Enlightenment happen to them the real reason for prosperity, say had the Islam Golden Age lasted longer maybe Arabic countries could have had similar colonial and scientific success. First country to get here gets exponential benefits posteriori, but it is a complete matter of luck who gets to that point first )
I have heard that the original thesis by Weber has been disproved. Is this true? Is the idea still considered true or at least mainstream at large, not in the specific details but the general idea?
In other words are there still sociologists that defend the idea a who?
Sources: (I don't have one for the claim that the thesis was disproven) http://workethic.coe.uga.edu/hpro.html#:~:text=Calvin%20taught%20that%20all%20men,creation%20(Braude%2C%201975).
https://revisesociology.com/2018/08/17/max-weber-religion-society-change/
Also on the early history of colonies in the US: https://press-pubs.uchicago.edu/founders/print_documents/v1ch16s1.html

Comparative studies of economic success of one country versus another typically consider geographical determinism. No data exists that would support that religion matters at all. See Guns Germs and steel, and similar books. Also you should quote your sources in your questions.

I agree with Guns and Germs, I jus think that what allows you get the steel and guns is what gives you exponential growth. First person to get a gun in an island can get more food for generations and hence achieve hegemony very quickly and for centuries. The bigger point though it that you can use that same hegemony to get even better guns.
It is just I wonder if the reason why the US is so capitalist oriented (regardless of economic success) is because of the psychological analysis that I mentioned(fear of hell leads to dilligence)

This might be relevant to your readings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosperity_theology Part of the question that would have to be resolved from a metaphysical perspective is "The Protestant Work Ethic is valid how according to whom?" There are other factors. Historian Yuval Harari in his Sapiens cites fractional lending as a marked advance, so in this sense, it might be the methods of banking, and not just the work ethic per se.

The USA is definitely an outlier in a lot of ways. Banking, as JD mentions, is a major enabler of capitalism. I think the 'Protestant' work ethic is really just a name for ordinary anxiety and the resulting efforts to stay safe.

early attempts at Christian communes with socialist-like organization are called abbey and monasteries, and they are doing fine (except maybe a recent difficulty to renew their membership, more linked to the regress of adherence to religion)

Wow I just asked this in reddit and they were as useless as this dump of a site and did not downvote me for no reason
